# Troubles with getting sub-categories of main category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to learn Laravel while writing some common features. Now what I'm trying to make is when I click on main category link to open new page and display all sub-categories assigned to this category. Sounds pretty simple but I can't display them.

This is what I have in my Category Model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

And in controller

```
public function categoryListing( $category_id )
{

    $categories = Category::with('children')->get();    

    $category = Category::find($category_id);

    if($category->parent_id == 0) {

         $ids = Category::select('id')->where('parent_id', '!=',0)->get();
         $array = array();

         foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $array[] = (int) $id->id;
         }

    } else {
        $items =  Item::where('category_id' ,$category_id)->paginate(5);
    }

    return view('category_list', compact('categories','items'));
}
```

The idea here is to display Main Category and all sub-categories (childs) of this main category.
And this is the loop on the page

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <a href="{!!route('list',array($category->id))!!}">
        <span><strong>{!!$category->title!!}</strong> ({!! $category->itemCount!!})</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($category as $subcategory)
            <a href="{!!route('list',array($subcategory->id))!!}">{!!$subcategory->title!!}</a>
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{!! $subcategory->itemCount !!}</span>
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Current error is

> Trying to get property of non-object

on the inside foreach.

Comment: Can you please try with this `$subcategory['title'];` and `$subcategory['temCount'];` inside foreach.

Comment: It is returning something wired. The results are all categories and subcategories on first foreach. Second foreach where sub-categories should be displayed is empty

Comment: I know that is totally mess and probably there is cleaner and easier way to rend main category with sub-categories assigned to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this is 'cleaner'.. if it works, start adding your links and other content so you will know what does not work.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <span><strong>{!!$category->title!!}</strong></span>
     <ul class="list-group">
       @foreach($category as $subcategory)
          <li>{!!$subcategory->title!!}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Make sure the variables you try to print exist in each object.

You can try to `dd($categories);` in your controller before the   return `view('category_list', compact('categories','items'));` statement to see whats inside `$categories`

Comment: Thanks but getting "Trying to get non-object..." in second foreach line `{!!$subcategory->title!!}`. I've tried to change `{!!$subcategory['title']!!}` and it's empty. `dd($categories);` return all categories instead of the single category which I clicked on and the id is `$category_id`